# How to get peer IP address using wxTCPServer, wxTCPClient, wxTCPConnection?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, ip-address, wxwidgets

I'm writing my own C++ lib for TCP communications using `wxTCPServer` / `wxTCPClient`. `wxTCPConnection` class represents the connection itself (at each side). `wxWidgets` version is 3.0.2.

Everything is good, I'm able to communicate and transfer the data between client and server, but I see no ways how to determine peer IP address...

I think it's very important, some servers may need to know IP address for IP filtering or at least for proper logging of the connections and/or communications.

I also had a look at `wxSocketServer` / `wxSocketClient`, but it looks like there are no ways to determine peer IP address too.

So, the questions are:

1. **How can I determine client address** in `wxTCPServer::OnAcceptConnection(const wxString& topic)`? Strange, but it looks like there are no such data provided by `wxTCPServer` or `wxTCPConnection`. I have found nothing about it in wxWidgets documentation and wherever else.
2. **Other simple ways to implement cross-platform (Linux+MSW) TCP(?) client/server communications** using free/GPL libs?  I don't really need all the TCP(?) stuff implemented in wxWidgets like `topic` and `item`, I need only the following:

   - to connect using host name (or IP) and port number,
   - have access to peer ip when it's connecting (to receive/refuse incoming connection),
   - send and receive byte sequences up to, say, 1Mb at once,
   - automatic transfer error correction will be good to have.

I'll handle everything else (my own protocol) by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The IPC classes in wxWidgets are meant to abstract you from the TCP details such as IP addresses, in fact they can be used with DDE under MSW, in which case the question of the IP address doesn't really make sense.

You can use `wxSocket` directly and then you would be able to call `GetPeer()` to get the remote address.